# How to add input into a text based program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a text based RPG using Python. At the moment when you execute the program it brings you through an introduction and at the end of it i have the user decide to go 1.Left 2. Right 3. Middle. Each place has a unique item needed to complete the game, meaning if you go to the right it will see if you have a specific item appended to your bag. If you do not have it you will return to the main part to decide where to go again. That being said the middle is the main part where i want the user to be able to attack a dragon right away so they can lose, or if prepared with the necessary items appended, win! Now you do not have the option to attack, you just get to the dragon and win, so there is no lose. Any tips of how to incorporate an input throughout the game would be helpful. If more information is needed i can gladly share :).

I tried implementing an input before attacking the dragon but it got caught inside the loop so even when you obtained all the items you would get returned to the main dungeon. Here is a snippet code for the final dungeon for an idea.

```py
def valid_input(prompt, option1, option2):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt).lower()
        if option1 in response:
            print_pause("You use the " + str(Weapon) + " against the dragon")
            print_pause("But it is not strong enough "
                        "to defeat the dragon, he uses Fire Breath"
                        " and, he incinerates you! ")
            print_pause("You lose!")
            play_again()
            break
        elif option2 in response:
            print_pause("Smart Choice! You head back to the main dungeon")
            dungeon_game()
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, try again")
    return response


def middle_dungeon():
    print_pause("You go to the middle dungeon.")
    print_pause("After a few moments,"
                " you find yourself in front of a " + Dragon + "!")
    print_pause("This is why you need these magical powers.")

    if "MagicRune" in bag:
        print_pause("Luckily the Wizard trained you well, you now obtain "
                    " the power of the " + str(MagicRune) + "!")
        print_pause("You attack the dragon! ")
    if "MagicRune" not in bag:
        print_pause("You do not obtain the necessary magical powers.")
        print_pause("It looks like you need a scroll or more power!.")
        print_pause("You head back to the main dungeon.")   
        dungeon_game()

    dragon_health = 100
    count = 0
    while dragon_health > 0:
        damage_by_player = random.randint(0, 60)
        print_pause(f"You hit the dragon and caused {damage_by_player} damage")
        dragon_health = dragon_health - damage_by_player
        print_pause(f"dragon health is now {dragon_health}")
        count = count + 1

    print_pause(f"You successfully defeated the dragon in {count} attempts, you win!")
    play_again()

def dungeon_game():
    passage = ''
    if 'started' not in Dungeon:
        display_intro()
        Dungeon.append('started')
        while passage != '1' and passage != '2' and passage != '3':
            passage = input("1. Left\n"
                            "2. Right\n"
                            "3. Middle\n")
            if passage == '1':
                left_dungeon()
            elif passage == '2':
                right_dungeon()
            elif passage == '3':
                middle_dungeon()
                dungeon_game()
```

So essentially this output will deny you until you go to the left dungeon and right dungeon, where you see MagicRune in bag: this will let you go to the dragon while loop and win the game.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How would you implement an input that does not get caught in a loop? Do i create a function that contains the input and use a function call? i am stuck on being able to add a decision for the user playing.

Comment: You said you tried implementing an input "but it got caught inside the loop". I'm not sure exactly what that means. Can you post the code you tried and explain exactly how it failed?

Comment: yeah let edit the code. Ill show you the function i created and want to use in the existing code above.

Comment: So, the function above i do not actually call it because it wouldnt work, but its an idea of what i want to do. I want to have asked if they want to attack or not after the print statements in middle_dungeon. if they do initially without the appended items it would kill them and ask if they want to play again. Otherwise, when the items are properly appended have them able to use the item  which has a random.choice connected and then move through the rest of the middle_dungeon where they would attack the dragon. Not sure if that is even possible, or if there is an easier way to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange your code a bit. Here's how you could change your input function:

```
def valid_input(prompt, option1, option2):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt).lower()
        if option1 in response:
            return option1
        elif option2 in response:
            return option2
        else:
            print("Sorry, try again")
```

Now it returns the option the user chose and lets the calling code determine what to do with that information. This makes it actually reusable. You'd call it like this:

```
chosen = valid_input("Wanna attack the dragon?", "yes", "no")
if chosen == "yes":
    # do that stuff
else:
    # do other stuff
```

You also have another problem that you really need to fix: you are treating function calls like `goto` statements. This will cause you pain when you're trying to debug your code, and also causes hard-to-track bugs.

For example, you should not call `play_again()` to restart your code. Instead, set up your code structure so that you don't have to do that. E.g.

```
def dungeon_game():  
  while True:
    # set up initial game state here, e.g.
    bag = ["sword", "potion"]
    # call main game logic function
    dungeon()    
    # that function returned, so the game is over.
    want_to_play = input("play again?")
    if want_to_play == "no":
      # if we don't break, the While loop will start the game again
      break

def dungeon():
  # blah blah dragon attack
  if (whatever):
    print("You got killed. Game over.")
    return # goes back to dungeon_game()
  else:
    print("You won the fight")
  # code for the next thing that happens...

if __name__ == "__main__":
  dungeon_game()
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh, this makes much more sense. I really appreciate the input. I will see what i can do to change it around a little. Thank you for taking the time to help out :)

Comment: So i have a left_dungeon() right_dungeon() and middle_dungeon(). I'll share at the bottom my dungeon_game() to show you how i had it , because it goes through all three dungeons in order to append the items. So i am having trouble putting the lists. You're saying i should get rid of this structure all together, correct?

Comment: Your `dungeon_game` looks basically ok, except for that last line where you call `dungeon_game` from inside `dungeon_game`. In general, if you take the list of functions that were called to get to the line of code that's executing (e.g.  `dungeon_game` -> `middle_dungeon`), you should never call a function that's already in that list. If you're in `middle_dungeon` and you want to go back to `dungeon_game`, just `return` from `middle_dungeon`. If you're in `dungeon_game` and want to "start again", set up a loop that will do that. Etc.

Comment: Got it, and i have changed that. Now i just need to figure out how to get the game to reset when i use the `play_again()` function. - again truly appreciate your time and input.